# Blueprint XML file scanning with Gradle OSGI plugin

Tags: java, gradle, blueprint-osgi

I'm investigating migrating an existing OSGI/blueprint project from Maven to Gradle. In Maven the maven-bundle-plugin plugin scans context XML files for imports that might not occur in the code, however I can't get this to work with the Gradle OSGI plugin.

For example, blueprint XML contains an import like this

```
<reference id="exampleService" availability="mandatory" interface="com.adamish.test.Test" />
```

### Maven

Using the `Bundle-Blueprint` instruction in the POM with maven-bundle-plugin...

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <instructions>
        <Bundle-Blueprint>OSGI-INF/blueprint/context.xml</Bundle-Blueprint> 
        </instructions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Then the generated MANFEST.MF will contain an import like this

```
Import-Package: com.adamish.test
```

### Gradle

However using the following build.gradle file does not generate a MANIFEST.MF with a Import-Package for com.adamish.test

```
apply plugin: 'osgi'

jar {
    manifest {
        instruction 'Bundle-Blueprint', 'OSGI-INF/blueprint/context.xml'
    }
}
```

### Analysis

Both Maven and Gradle use BND which seems to contain the Bundle-Blueprint instruction, however when invoked via Gradle it does not cause imports to be added to the MANIFEST.

I've tested this in Gradle 2.4 and now latest 2.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Blueprint parsing capability of maven-bundle-plugin is provided by the class [BlueprintPlugin](https://github.com/apache/felix/blob/ac5ec40ee40ec92dc8124e22afa855ab2c4a850f/tools/maven-bundle-plugin/src/main/java/org/apache/felix/bundleplugin/BlueprintPlugin.java) part of maven-bundle-plugin, not BND. BND does contain some blueprint-aware code, however that is part of a [repoindex command tool](https://github.com/bndtools/bnd/blob/master/REPOINDEX.md).

I've been able to workaround this issue temporarily by parsing the XML files manually and building list of Java packages

```
def importPackages = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
fileTree(dir: 'src/main/resources/OSGI-INF/blueprint/', include: '*.xml').each {
   new XmlSlurper().parse(it).'**'.findAll { it.@availability == "mandatory" }.each {
      def iFace = it.@interface.text()
      importPackages.add(iFace.substring(0, iFace.lastIndexOf('.')))
   }
}

importPackages.add('com.adamish.foo')

jar {
    manifest {
        instruction 'Import-Package', importPackages.join(',')
    }
}
```

Comment: If I were you, I'd use LinkedHashSet so that `importPackages.join(',')
` is [deterministic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_system)

Comment: Instead of modifying the jar step, I chose to explicitly mention the packages in the source `bnd.bnd` like so: `Import-Package: ${project.ext.blueprintInterfaces}` and `return importBlueprintPackages.join(',')` from your function. I then have to add a `task loadBlueprintClasses {
    project.ext.blueprintInterfaces = processBlueprintInterfaces()
}` Nice one Adam!